# Properties of connection Laplacian on vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

Let $(M,g)$ be a simply-connected compact surface with boundary $\partial M$ and metric $g$. Let $N$ denote the outward unit normal on $\partial M$, $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection and $\Delta_g$ the corresponding connection Laplacian (i.e. the trace of the Hessian).

I am interested in the properties of the vector field $X$ that minimises
$\int_M \langle \nabla X, \nabla X\rangle dV$ subject to the boundary condition $\nabla_N X=0$, where $\langle,\rangle$ denotes the extension of g to arbitrary tensor fields. Because of these boundary conditions, $\int_M \langle \nabla X, \nabla X\rangle dV=-\int_M \langle \Delta_g X, X\rangle dV$ and we just need the lowest eigenvalue of the Laplacian with these boundary conditions.

I am not sure this boundary problem is well posed, but if so, this eigenvalue cannot be zero in general, since there are no parallel vector fields on a curved surface by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. It is my hope that a general solution to this boundary problem exists, and that the lowest eigenvalue can be expressed in terms of the Gauss curvature of the surface. I would be very grateful for an answer to this question, and ideally a reference that deals with this problem in more detail, since all books I can find deal with the Hodge Laplacian.

Comment: The existence   follows from  basic facts about  elliptic  boundary value problems. I  do not  believe that the lowest eigenvalue can be expressed in a simple way in terms of the Gaussian curvature alone . To see what could happen start with the simple case when $M$ is the unit flat disk in the plane then slightly perturb the metric and see what  happens with the first eigenvalue. The computations may not be too pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such a result is possible without any assumptions on the geometry of the boundary.

Consider the scalar case. If $M$ is a closed manifold with $\operatorname{Ric} \geq (n-1)k g$ for some positive constant $k$, then $\lambda_1(M) \geq nk$. The proof (which is due to Lichnerowicz and is summarized in Obata's paper *Certain conditions for a Riemannian manifold to be isometric with a sphere*) uses integration by parts, so one has to be careful when $\partial M$ is nontrivial. This was studied by Reilly in *Applications of the Hessian operator on a Riemannian manifold*. He proved that the same lower bound for the first (Dirichlet) eigenvalue holds as long as $\partial M$ has nonpositive mean curvature.

The proof is just a computation, so it should be straightforward (though tedious) to see if a similar result holds for the connection Laplacian on vector fields.